# dowload file to my documents folder from using share point code, getting 403 forbidden error on site

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to download multiple files from gridView by selecting checkbox( on SharePoint site), Actually it will fetch the file using SharePoint ID from list in the SharePoint site and write it my documents folder and then zip it.

all the functionalities working in development server, I am able to download as zip file in the my documents folder in the system.

Note: The same code deployed to QA environment, I tried to download it, but I am getting the 403 forbidden error. I could not able to download it.

Could someone please help me on this issue.

```
  protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
  {
      int counter=0;
      bool dataSel=false;
      for(int i=0;i<gridviewestimates.rows.count; i++)
      {
         checkbox chkselect= 
        (checkboc)gridviewestimates.rows[i].findcontrol("chkselect");
        try
        {
           if(chkselect.checked)
            {
              counter++;
              Label lblspitemid= 
              (label)gridviewestimates.rows[i].findcontrol("lblspitemid");
              
              addfiletodictionary("Estimate 
              Documents",convert.ToInt32(lblSPItemId.Text));
              dataSel=true;
            }
        }
        

        catch(Exception ex) {throw ex;}
      }

         if(counter <=0)
         {
           
    page.clientscript.registerstartupscript(GetType(),"msgbox","alert('Please 
    select the checkbox to download files');",true);
           
          }
           if(dataSel)
           {
               callzipmethod();
          }
     }

private void callzipmethod()
 {
     string path=path.combine(environment.getfolderpath                
     (environment.specialfolder.mydocument),"KKM Estimate Documents");
      try
      {
          string sourcePath=path;
          string 
    docPath=environment.getfolderpath(environment.specialfolder.mydocuments);
    
    string 
    destinationPath=docPath+"\\"+"KKM_Estimates_"+datetime.now.tostring                        
    ("MM_dd_yyyy HH.mm tt")+".zip";
    
    string[] filenames=Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

           using(ZipOutputStream outputstream=new ZipOutputStream(File.Create                
           (destionationPath)))
            {
                outputstream.setlevel(9);
                byte[] buffer=new byte[40000];
                foreach(string file in filenames)
                {
                    ZipEntry entry=new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));
                    entry.DateTime=DateTime.Now;
                    outputstream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                    using(FileStream fs=File.OpenRead(file))
                    {
                        int sourceBytes;
                        do
                        {
                        sourceBytes=fs.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
                        outputstream.Write(buffer,0,sourceBytes);
                        }while(sourceBytes > 0);
                    }
                }
                outputstream.Finish();
                outputstream.Close();                       
            Page.clientscript.registerstartupscript(GetType()."msgbox","alert
           ('KKM_Estiates_ 
           "+DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy HH.mm tt")+ ".zip downloaded 
           inside MyDocuments folder');",true);                
           }
               
      }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
            throw ex;
         }
         string[] files=Directory.GetFiles(path);
         foreach(string file in files)
         {
             var name=new FileInfo(file).Name;
             File.Delete(file);
         }
         if(Directory.Exists(path))
         {
             Directory.Delete(path);
         }
}
```

---

```
 private void AddFileToDictionary(string libraryName,int documentId)
{
    SPSite site=new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
    SPWeb web=site.OpenWeb();
    SPList docLib=web.Lists[libraryName];
    SPListItem item=docLib.GetItemById(documentId);

    SPFile docFile=item.File;
    byte[] b=docFile.OpenBinary();

    string date=DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy HH.mm tt");

    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "KKM Estimate Documents"));
    string path=Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "KKM Estimate Documents");

     string fullPath=path+"\\"+docFile.Name;
     FileStream stream=new FileStream(fullPath,FileMode.Create);
     stream.Write(b,0,b.length);
     stream.Close();
 }
```

---

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Can you please provide some code that's failing?

Comment: Hi, The code is working in development environment,but I am getting forbidden error in QA(testing) enviornment. The website requires you to log in

Comment: Hi Boland, added code below for your review

Comment: Can somebody, please advise on this